# Minecraft Get the object from a list and be abbe to manipulate it

Tags: java, arraylist, minecraft

Hey in my minecraft mod I am trying to get the near entity's from my entity and be able to manipulate them.

This is the way I have been getting the near entitys:

```
    List entitylist = this.getEntityWorld().getEntitiesWithinAABBExcludingEntity(this, this.getEntityBoundingBox().expand(5.0D, 10.0D, 5.0D));
```

So how do I get the entitys out of the list?

Comment: entityList.get(index) or a simple foreach?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might do it :)

```
List entitylist = this.getEntityWorld().getEntitiesWithinAABBExcludingEntity(this, this.getEntityBoundingBox().expand(5.0D, 10.0D, 5.0D));
for (int i = 0; i < entitylist.size(); i++) {
 //Do stuff with each entity  
 Entity entity = (Entity) entitylist.get(i);
}
```

Comment: I changed it no.
As i'm not totally sure what the Entity Class name for Bukkit/Minecraft/Spigot is i used Entity in my updated answer

Comment: He wants get all the entity that are out of another entity range, and he is using forge.

Comment: To be honest ... I don't think your code would compile. Since `entitylist` is a raw-type, how should `#get()` be able to return a specific type?

Comment: Since entitylist is of the type List it should have the method that class have, including size,get and so on.

Comment: Agree with @Tom, objects from entitylist need to be casted

Comment: @KasperFranz And how does your compiler know, that it contains `Entity`? It is currently a raw-type, so it doesn't know the generic type.

Comment: You are right, I haven't used Java for some time (since i finished my AP i Computer Science 1½ year ago), PHP is a bit more do what ever you want ;)

I have updated my answer with a typecast :)

Comment: You also probably need to check that each object is really is an Entity, via ```instanceof```, but now I'm just nitpicking :)

Comment: It's weird that a Minecraft library is using rawtypes at all. The last I checked generics were already a part of Java when Minecraft was released. Maybe the library was written by a PHP developer, the "do whatever you want" language :-D

Comment: I Normally do that to but this was just a simple quick example :)

Comment: Haha @DavidS, I asked for that one myself ;)

Comment: @DavidS Sometimes I just do not want to know what is going on "under the hood" ... it would be just sad :D.

Comment: @Tom  You mean you dont like tweets like this https://twitter.com/SeargeDP/status/610834862111617024 

sometimes it's amazing the "car" even can drive ^^

Answer (score 0):

This code should work!, it get all the entity out of the selected entity

```
// World of the entity
World entityWorld = getEntityWorld();

// Who is near the entity ?
List nearEntities = entityWorld.getEntitiesWithinAABBExcludingEntity(this, getEntityBoundingBox().expand(5.0D, 10.0D, 5.0D));

// All the entity in the world
List allEntities = entityWorld.loadedEntityList;

// Create a new list that will contains the outer entity
List<Entity> outerEntities = new ArrayList<Entity>();

// Add all the entity in the world to the list
outerEntities.addAll(allEntities);

// Remove all the near entity
outerEntities.removeAll(nearEntities); 

// outerEntity now contains all outer entity
for (Entity outerEntity : outerEntities) {
    // Action on outer entity
}
```

Comment: You might want to put everything into sets here... I believe List.removeAll is O(n^2). That said, I have no idea how many objects we're talking about. (I'm just assuming there are *lots*.)

Comment: @burnsy Usually they are a near 100 so this code don't require so much time to get done, the really slow part is calculating near entity with getEntitiesWithinAABBExcludingEntity

Answer (score 0):

Your `entitylist` is something that now *contains* objects. In this case, you would say, "it's a list that contains entities". (I'm just assuming they are entities... We don't know for sure!)

You can look at each thing in the list using a for-loop, like this:

```
for (Object entity : entitylist){ //for each entity in the list
    if (o instanceof EntityLiving){ //<-- replace EntityLiving with what you expect

        ((EntityLiving) o).doStuff() //for example... I'm not familiar with Minecraft code!
        //...etc
    }
}
```

(This is more complicated than it should be, because the Minecraft code is strange, and doesn't tell us what type of thing is contained in the list. Just my opinion!)

Comment: He wants get all the entity that are out of another entity range